# Unzip single file from zip archive using node.js zlib module

Tags: node.js, zlib, unzip

Let say I have a **zip** archive `test.zip` which contained two files:

`test1.txt` and `text2.txt`

I want to extract only `test1.txt` using the node inbuilt `zlib` module.

How to do that?

I don't want to install any package.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a shell command to unzip, assuming that unzip is installed on your system. (It very likely is.)

As far as I can tell, there is no zip functionality within node.js without installing a package.

You can use zlib to help you with the decompression part, but you will have to write your own code to interpret the zip format. You can use `zlib.inflateRaw` to decompress the raw deflate compressed data of a zip entry. You have to first find where that compressed data starts by reading and interpreting the zip file headers.

The zip format is documented [here](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).